# Windows forms font weight

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to use a thin font weight in my win forms window. The only thing I've been able to find is FontStyle, but I can only choose from Bold, Italic, Regular, Strikeout and underline. No possibility to make my font thin. Preferably, I'd like to be able to specify the font weight (100, 200 etc).

Comment: I don't think you can access FontWeight in Windows Forms (it's available in WPF).  Just use a thinner font such as Segoe UI Light as a workaround.

Comment: You do the exact same thing you do in Microsoft Word and all other Windows applications: you use a font that supports the weight you desire. But I strongly recommend against it. **Use the default system font, the one that the user picked for their applications: [`SystemFonts.MessageBoxFont`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemfonts.messageboxfont.aspx).** It is the one that they prefer *and find the most readable*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to include a font file of a thin weight font in your deployment.

Then you can use it within your app.

This will likely cost you licensing I'm afraid. Wpf does make it easier so might be a more viable option depending on how great the need and how great the budget.

Comment: I have a file with a thin version of the font (it's Roboto, I downloaded regular, bold and thin). I am loading all 3 from resources using PrivateFontCollection. How do I go about choosing the thin one?

Comment: You'll only be able to if it installs them into windows as three seperate fonts. Easiest way to check is with MS Word. If you see Roboto listed three times, you should be able to direct you app to use the one which represents thin. Remember to include it in your application installer.

Comment: I just noticed the PrivateFontCollection has 2 font families: "Roboto" and "Roboto Thin" - so I'm gonna take a wild guess and try the second one

Answer (score 2):

I've not tried it, but looking through [CreateFont](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function I believe it can certainly be done via [P/Invoking CreateFont function](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32.createfont).

It takes a parameter `fnWeight` which is font weight. Then you could call [Font.FromHFont](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.fromhfont%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to get the instance of Font.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't do it directly.

That being said, you [embed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-s/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(v=vs.110).aspx) WPF controls in Windows Forms pretty easily, and WPF controls have font weight property exposed directly.  Perhaps that might be suitable?