# Set fontWeight in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, fonts

My question is quite clear, I'd like to have more font-weight options than just regular and bold. I'd prefer to just use an int for the font-weight.

Comment: Actually... it's not so clear.  WPF? Silverlight?  WinForms?  HTML?

Comment: True Added the winforms tag :P

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249167/windows-forms-font-weight

Comment: OpenType has more options.  Not supported by Winforms.  Some TrueType fonts expose options by font name.  Check Franklin Gothic for example.