How do I use font weights other than Regular and Bold? (C# WinForms)
I'm trying to use the SF Mono font in the Medium weight. The FontStyle argument doesn't seem to work with "Medium", and wants either Regular or Bold. This locks me out of Light and Heavy too. Code:
this.richTextBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("SF Mono", 10.2F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Medium, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));

(this is my first post here)
I have tried manually typing it in, but it reverts to MicrosoftSansSerif. Didn't expect that to work, but is there any other way to use other weights from the font than Regular and Bold?

All possible font styles are defined in the documentation: FontStyle Enum and this is what you are marked in your question.  If you cann't  to achieve what you need using the existing parameters, you need find another font (custom) that will fit your requirements.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/25249167/14171304

The font has all weights installed though, as different TTF files. But they all seem to merge into one. So I don’t think that thread solves it. Btw, that question is as old as time.

Time repeats itself for those who do not learn. How can we convince you that no font weight concept in WinForms? You need to find a way to get around the limitations and the referred link provides some ways. Copy?
